# Can not connect to ssh over network

Tags: ssh

### Overview

I can not connect to a host via ssh.
I have 2 macs, both on the same wifi. Mac `A` can connect to a VPN and ssh into machines over wifi. Mac `B` can connect to the VPN but can not ssh.

Both machines have the same `.pem` file, in the same location, the permission is set to `chmod 400` (`-r--------`). Both also have the same `~/.ssh/config` files.

**From the investigating that I have done this does not seem to be a server issue, and I think it is a problem with mac `B` and its network settings.**

### Working Machine -- Mac `A`

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/matthewlowe/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/matthewlowe/.ssh/config line 8: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/matthewlowe/.ssh/config line 21: Applying options for *.internal
debug2: add_identity_file: ignoring duplicate key ~/.ssh/innometrics.pem
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "ip-10-0-4-139.eu-west-1.compute.internal" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ip-10-0-4-139.eu-west-1.compute.internal [10.0.4.139] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
```

### Failing Machine -- Mac `B`

When running `ssh -vvv ipaddress.eu-west-1.compute.internal` I get the following:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/username/.ssh/config line 8: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/username/.ssh/config line 21: Applying options for *.internal
debug2: add_identity_file: ignoring duplicate key ~/.ssh/username.pem
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "ipaddress.eu-west-1.compute.internal" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ipaddress.eu-west-1.compute.internal [xx.x.x.xxx] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: connect to address xx.x.x.xxx port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host ipaddress.eu-west-1.compute.internal port 22: Operation timed out
```

What does `fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK` do? I gathered that `fd 3` is looking for a file descriptor #3 and have found that dir on my machine. Why would it timeout here?

This doesnt seem to be a DNS issue, as the DNS name I provide is then resolved to the correct AWS IP.

### Additional Details

`Firewall: Off`

Wifi Settings

```
Using DHCP
DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
NetBIOS Name: IP-192-168-1-63 (IP-192-168-1-63 is currently being used)
Hardware configured automatically, MTU 1500
```

From `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` The only active part:

```
 Host *
   SendEnv LANG LC_*
   HashKnownHosts yes
   GSSAPIAuthentication yes
   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

And the same from `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
UseDNS no
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
```

The working machine also has `XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth` though I dont know if that is relevant or not.

I have tried a wired connection and that does not work either.

I can post additional information if needed.

Papa Bless.

### UPDATE #1

I have reinstalled openssh and open ssl. `/usr/local/bin/` shows the correct sym link to the installed versions. I am not using an older version by mistake.

I have run `ifconfig` to compare the wifi network interfaces. I have also run `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I en1` to dig a little deeper into it. All looks normal though.

### UPdate #2

Running `route -n get dnsnamehere` on `A`:

```
17:36 $ route -n get ip-10-0-2-121.eu-west-1.compute.internal
  route to: xx.x.x.xxx
destination: xx.x.x.xxx
 interface: ppp0
     flags: <UP,HOST,DONE,WASCLONED,IFSCOPE,IFREF>
recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
      0         0         0        52         2         0      1444         0
```

Running the same on `B`:

```
17:31 $ route -n get ip-10-0-2-121.eu-west-1.compute.internal
   route to: xx.x.x.xxx
destination: xx.x.x.xxx
    gateway: 192.168.1.1
  interface: en0
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,HOST,DONE,WASCLONED,IFSCOPE,IFREF>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1453         0
```

We also have machine `C` that looks similar to the results of `A`. Looks like the bad machine is routing through the wifi `en0` rather than through the VPN (`ppp0`)? If this is the case, how do I fix it?

Comment: Even if you doubt the problem to be server related, it could well be since the VPN connection works on machine B.  Do you have other servers that you can test with?  Did you check the server's firewall to see if it blocked anything?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @JuliePelletier. The VPN is used to access all of our AWS instances. I can not ssh into any of the instances on mac `B`. It blocks on `debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK`.

Comment: If you verify the connection that works, you should notice that same line so it's irrelevant to your problem.  Since the problem is apparently on Mac B, it is possible that it routes all traffic to its local interface instead of the VPN.  Compare the routing tables on both machines when the VPN is up to check that.

Comment: I have updated my question with the output from mac `A`, as it could be useful. I can add that when you run `traceroute` on `A` you get the correct end point, on `B` you are bounced around to 6 or so and never reach the real end point.

Comment: Do both `traceroute`s go through the same path?  (probably not)  As I said, compare the routing tables on both machines when the VPN is up: `route -n`.

Comment: `traceroute` for `A` goes direct to the host machine, for `B` it goes everywhere but the host. We have a 3rd machine `C` which performs like `A` and is working. How do you use the `route -n` command on the mac?

Comment: I have updated the question with the `route` results. @JuliePelletier

Comment: Then you obviously need to correct the route.  I suspect there may be a bad configuration in your VPN client that causes it not to set the default route but that is uncertain, especially without seeing the actual routing table.  The answer from @poixen might do the job but it may also give you problems once you disconnect the VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First flush the routing tables of all gateway entries:

`sudo route flush`

Then route all traffic that fall under `10/16` to the `ppp0`:

`sudo route add -host 10.0.0.0 -netmask 255.255.0.0 -interface ppp0`